# How connect Azure Function with my own model? It is possible to use Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

#### Intro

I created my own model locally and then register it and deploy it to azure and it works.

#### deployed model output:

[image]

#### my approach

I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/deploying-azure-machine-learning-containers-41bcb02a4e1b), and I want use my model in Azure Function and I can do it:

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[func.QueueMessage]) -> str:
    name = req.params.get('name')
    scoring_uri = 'http://1f72b1bf-5ca9-42d9-bedd-f41773591a4f.francecentral.azurecontainer.io/score'
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    test_data = json.dumps({'text': 'Today is a great day!'})
    response = requests.post(scoring_uri, data=test_data, headers=headers)

if not name:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        name = req_body.get('name')

if name:
    msg.set(name)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! Najlepszy wynik: {response.json()}")
else:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
        status_code=400
    )
```

#### questions

1. Is my usage correct?
2. Is it possible to use azure storage for model storage and how to do it?
3. Is there any other way to use the model in Azure Function?

I am wondering because I had specified in the requirements that I should use azure functions and azure storage. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the deployment of a ML model to Azure Functions is in preview.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-functions